# Manejar diferentes estilos de fuente con css

Tags: fuentes, google-fonts

Un gran saludo:

Sucede que una fuente de texto tiene diferentes variaciones, en este caso yo he optado por escoger la open sans, que tiene fuente light, regular, bold, extrabold, el caso es que yo deseo variar en las fuentes, que la primera sea bold, la segunda regular, la tercera light, pero solo me sale una opción y al colocar font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  no se aprecia ninguna variación entre las palabras, todo el texto sale igual.

Gracias

```css
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
</style>

#t3{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
}

#t4{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
}


#t5{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="titular"><div id="t3"> MODELANDO</div> <div id="t4">LAS IDEAS</div><div id="t5">CON CREATIVIDAD</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que tienes que agregar en el HTML las variaciones de las fuentes. Según lo que leí tendría que quedar así:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

Cuéntame si te funciono, saludos.